# Ampersand in object's properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm writing a JS script that has an object with &'s in some of its properties, e.g.

```js
var topicObj = {
"Client & Peripherals": ["USB", "Printer", "Copy/Paste"],
"Install & Upgrade": ["Tenant Upgrade", "Agent upgrade"]
}
```

The thing is, when I attempt to iterate over one of its values, e.g.

```js
selMTopic = "Client & Peripherals"
for (t in topicObj[selMTopic]) {
  addTopic(topicsDD,topicObj[selMTopic][t]);
}
```

it fails, it can't compute *t*, I guess it doesn't like having &'s, and similar characters, in the property.

I've been trying to find out how to have and use &'s in properties with no luck; I've tried encoding the string with *encodeURIComponent* but no luck either.

Any idea how can I do it, if possible? I need to have those &'s there. I'm thinking it using two arrays instead of the object, one with the object's properties, and the other each of the object's value arrays; but I would really rather stick with an object, as I may need to add more "levels of depth" in the future.

Comment: Avoid `for..in` for arrays. Try `forEach`.

Comment: There is no problem using `&` in an object's key. Without knowing what `addTopic` there's no way to reproduce the issue. Are you getting strings for `selMTopic` in such a way that the ampersand is encoded?

Comment: As Mark Meyer said, for..in doesn't fail due to any special characters in object property names. You have made some other mistake in your code leading to this issue. The problem is not related to which characters are in the property names.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkMeyer and @ChrisRollings! It would seem that it has something to do with the encoding or something, because If I use Mr. Jojo's example, but assigning one value to _selMTopic_, `selMTopic = "HCS - Client & Peripherals"` works fine, the console gets the expected outcome, but `selMTopic = document.getElementById("MainTBtn").innerHTML` returns "DropTest MultiDD.htm:239 Uncaught TypeError: topicObj[selMTopic] is not iterable at resetTopics (DropTest MultiDD.htm:239)" (Chr) or "Uncaught TypeError: topicObj[selMTopic] is undefined, resetTopics file:///.../DropTest MultiDD.htm:239" (FF)

Comment: I have `charset="UTF-8"` in my `<meta>`

Comment: @PabloOrtiz this is all another question, you should open a new topic with your html (ps: there is no `dropdown-content` element in html)

Comment: Hey @MisterJojo, I understand. I just did, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64957107/of-ampersands-object-properties-and-buttons-innerhtmls) :)

Answer (score 1):

use **of** (for array) instead of **in** (for properties)

```js
var topicObj =
  { "Client & Peripherals" : ["USB", "Printer", "Copy/Paste"]
  , "Install & Upgrade"    : ["Tenant Upgrade", "Agent upgrade"]
  }
for (let selMTopic in topicObj)
  {
  for (let t of topicObj[selMTopic])
    {
    console.log( selMTopic,'->', t )
    // addTopic(topicsDD, t );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I guess it has something to do with the encoding, or something, as @Mark and @Chris mentioned above, because if I use your code in my script and run
`selMTopic = "Client & Peripherals";
for (let t of topicObj[selMTopic])
{
 console.log( selMTopic,'->', t );
}`

I get,
Client & Peripherals -> USB
Client & Peripherals -> Printer
...

Comment: But if I run, as my code is, 
`selMTopic = document.getElementById("MainTBtn").innerHTML;
for (let t of topicObj[selMTopic])
{
 console.log( selMTopic,'->', t );
}` 

(document.getElementById("MainTBtn") is a <button> whose *innerHTML* is assigned one of the topicObj's properties selected from a dropdown-content)

I get "DropTest MultiDD.htm:239 Uncaught TypeError: topicObj[selMTopic] is not iterable 
    at resetTopics (DropTest MultiDD.htm:239)" (Chrome)
Or "Uncaught TypeError: topicObj[selMTopic] is undefined 
    resetTopics file:///.../DropTest MultiDD.htm:239